# Exponential group?

Tags: group-theory

Considering a suitable set of numbers, you can construct a group using addition, and you can construct another group using multiplication. My question: Can you construct a group using exponentiation?

- $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ is a group.
- $(\mathbb{R} \backslash 0, \times)$ is another group.
- Does there exist some $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $(S, \uparrow)$ is a group?

(Here $x \uparrow y = x^y$.)

I'm going to guess "no", since exponentiation is asymmetric and hence needs two inverses (roots and logarithms). So maybe you can have some other group-like structure? (But which one?)

Comment: You can have nonabelian groups. The main problem is that $\uparrow$ is not associative.

Comment: Oh man, I hadn't even _thought_ about associativity!

Comment: ;) You cannot go very far without it.

Comment: what happens if you consider ${0,1}$ as the candidates .

Comment: oh it doesn't help :P

Comment: Whether a group's binary operation is denoted $+$ or $\cdot$ is a notational convention that fits the better (more intuitive) frame of mind for a particular context. If we really wanted to, we could denote addition by $\cdot$ or multiplication by $+$, perhaps in a parallel universe, and there would be no issue. The real question is, in what conceptual sense could an arbitrary associative binary operation on a set be thought of as "exponentiation"? Fundamentally, I think exponentiation's moral purpose is to merely transfer from one structure to another - not build one from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^y$ is not even well-defined for many real arguments.  (For example, $(-2)^\frac12$.) You would have to begin by restricting the domain to non-negative reals.

But even then, exponentiation is not in general associative, since $x^{(y^z)} \ne  (x^y)^z$, and to make it associative you would have to restrict the domain so severely that what is left would not be very interesting.

Comment: Not associative. Definitely not a group then. Perhaps some kind of loop or quasigroup?

Comment: Well, if you restrict it to the set $\{1\}$…

Answer (score 8):

This isn't quite what you want, but it's a nice example and deserves to be widely known: the reals exceeding 1 form a (commutative!) group under the operation given by $a*b=a^{\log b}$.

Comment: Is that $>1$ or $\geq 1$? It seems like $1$ would serve as the identity, but you wrote reals exceeding one.

Comment: @chris the base of the logarithm. If you chose $\ln$ it will be $e$.

Comment: I realized after a bit more thought my earlier comment was incorrect. Thanks for the clarification. This is a nice example.

Comment: I like this answer.

Comment: It's interesting...where and how many times have you seen this example used?

Comment: @rschwieb, I have only ever seen it used as homework for students in the first weeks of a group theory class. I don't know of any non-pedagogic uses.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have a feeling it came out of *something* cool and interesting, so I had to ask :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson What about a directed graph where nodes are positive reals and each edge (from a to b) is labelled with log_a(b)? It seems to me that this is a monoid, and the label on the composition of two edges is just the product of their labels.